# increase int in textview after button click and keep it threw activities

Tags: android, textview

I'm new to android, and I'm stuck right now.
I'm building an android app. 
I have a textview with int value

```
final int intbut = 40;

hp.setText(String.valueOf(intbut));
```

I have a button, when clicking on it it add +1, +0 or -1 to the value.

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    if(answer.getHp() == 1){
                                        hp.setText(String.valueOf(intbut + 1));
                                        Log.i("GameActivity", "json " + answer.getHp());
                                }
```

But at the click of the button it also reload the activity so the new value is not saved, how can I save the changed value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be using [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), to save the desired value and retrieve it in any point of your application.

as an example this are create methods to save and retrieve and integer value:

```
private String PREFS_KEY = "mypreferences";

public void saveValuePref(Context context, int value) {
    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putInt("myValue", value);
    editor.commit();
}



public int getValuePref(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_KEY, MODE_PRIVATE);
    return  preferences.getInt("myValue", 0);
}
```

To save the value use:

```
saveValuePref(getApplicationContext, intbut);
```

to retrieve the value use:

```
int intbut = getValuePref(getApplicationContext);
```